# How to render circle sectors dynamically without using HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm making a wheel of fortune where I need to create a wheel, or a circle, based on no. of sectors and populate prize names.

I've done the code for a circle of fixed no. of sectors. Here is an example for a circle with 6 sectors.

```css
.wheel_container {
  position: relative;
  
  --wheel-size: 360px;
  width: var(--wheel-size);
  height: var(--wheel-size);
  
  margin-bottom: 2.4em;
}

.wheel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  --segment-deg: 60deg;
}

.wheel div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  width: calc((2 * 3.141592653589793 * (var(--wheel-size) / 2)) / 6);
  height: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  
  transform-origin: bottom;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.wheel div > span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wheel div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-3 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: crimson;
  transform: rotate(calc(-5 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(calc(-7 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: violet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-9 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(calc(-11 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}
```

```html
<div class='wheel_container'>
  <div class='wheel'>
    <div><span>Apple</span></div>
    <div><span>Durian</span></div>
    <div><span>Banana</span></div>
    <div><span>Mango</span></div>
    <div><span>Strawberry</span></div>
    <div><span>Jackfruit</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried calculating the circumference of the wheel divided by no. of sectors in `.wheel div`'s `width` property. But, it doesn't work because the polygon in `clip-path` is not curved, and the `<div>` box that holds it is still a box.

I could achieve what I want for a 6-sector circle with slight modification of adding some pixels on the `<div>` width.

```css
.wheel_container {
  position: relative;
  --wheel-size: 360px;
  width: var(--wheel-size);
  height: var(--wheel-size);
  margin-bottom: 2.4em;
}

.wheel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  --segment-deg: 60deg;
}

.wheel div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  
  /* Modification */
  width: calc((2 * 3.141592653589793 * ((var(--wheel-size) + 37px) / 2)) / 6);
  height: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.wheel div>span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wheel div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-3 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: crimson;
  transform: rotate(calc(-5 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(calc(-7 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: violet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-9 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(calc(-11 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}
```

```html
<div class='wheel_container'>
  <div class='wheel'>
    <div><span>Apple</span></div>
    <div><span>Durian</span></div>
    <div><span>Banana</span></div>
    <div><span>Mango</span></div>
    <div><span>Strawberry</span></div>
    <div><span>Jackfruit</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, the code for 6-sector wheel does not work for 8-sector wheel, etc...

I think the solution might lie in SVG filling rule with `clip-path`. However, my current knowlege of SVG ends here and I need some helping hands. Other ways of solution are also welcomed.

Comment: Have you thought of conic-gradients or alternatively transform rotate - you shouldn't need to do all that messy calculation, CSS + HTML will position things for you.

Comment: For 8 segments you will need: **1**. make `--segment-deg: 45deg;` since 360/8 = 45. **2** Also in order to calculate the width after `/* Modification */` you will need  `/ 8` instead of `/ 6`.  **3** Finally you will need to add the `.wheel div:nth-child(7) {` and `.wheel div:nth-child(8) {` roules and rotate those accordingly: `-13 * var(--segment-deg) / 2` and `-15 * var(--segment-deg) / 2`

Comment: @enxaneta That is my intention, yes. I will be manipulating CSS with JavaScript. But, as you can see in the first example, circle sectors are not fully filled. I want them evenly filled for all no. of segments, not just 6 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is the way you calculate the the width and the height of the `.wheel div`. If the height is the radius of the circle: `--radius: calc(var(--wheel-size) / 2 );` the width is `width: calc( 2 * var(--radius ) / 1.732);` where 1.732 is `Math.sqrt(3)`. This will work for a 6 segments wheel where the triangle (used for clip-path is equilateral.

In your example the width = radius. This is not enough since the div overflows the circle and you calculate the clip-path relativ to the size ofthe div.

In order to understand what happens remove the border-radius: 50%; and add a semitransparent unclipped segment to the wheel (clip-path: none;)

```js
console.log(Math.sqrt(3))
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}


.wheel_container {
  position: relative;
  
  --wheel-size: 360px;
  width: var(--wheel-size);
  height: var(--wheel-size);
  
  margin-bottom: 2.4em;
}

.wheel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  width: var(--wheel-size);
  height: var(--wheel-size);
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  --segment-deg: 60deg;
}

.wheel div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  
  --radius: calc(var(--wheel-size) / 2 );
  height: var(--radius);
  
  width: calc( 2 * var(--radius ) / 1.732);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  
  transform-origin: bottom;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.wheel div > span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wheel div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-3 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: crimson;
  transform: rotate(calc(-5 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(calc(-7 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: violet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-9 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(calc(-11 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}


..wheel div {transform:none!important}
```

```html
<div class='wheel_container'>
  <div class='wheel'>
    <div><span>Apple</span></div>
    <div><span>Durian</span></div>
    <div><span>Banana</span></div>
    <div><span>Mango</span></div>
    <div><span>Strawberry</span></div>
    <div><span>Jackfruit</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to go for 8 segments you will need a --segment-deg:45 and a different width of the `.wheel div`. I'm using `width: calc( 2 * var(--radius ) / 2.414);` where 2.414 is the tangent of (180 - 45) / 2.

```js
let a = 67.5;
const rad = Math.PI / 180;

console.log((Math.tan( a * rad)))
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}


.wheel_container {
  position: relative;
  
  --wheel-size: 360px;
  width: var(--wheel-size);
  height: var(--wheel-size);
  
  margin-bottom: 2.4em;
}

.wheel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  width: var(--wheel-size);
  height: var(--wheel-size);
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  --segment-deg: 45deg;
}

.wheel div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  
  --radius: calc(var(--wheel-size) / 2 );
  height: var(--radius);
  
  width: calc( 2 * var(--radius ) / 2.414);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  
  transform-origin: bottom;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.wheel div > span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wheel div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-3 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: crimson;
  transform: rotate(calc(-5 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(calc(-7 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: violet;
  transform: rotate(calc(-9 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(calc(-11 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}


.wheel div:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(calc(-13 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}

.wheel div:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(calc(-15 * var(--segment-deg) / 2));
}
```

```html
<div class='wheel_container'>
  <div class='wheel'>
    <div><span>Apple</span></div>
    <div><span>Durian</span></div>
    <div><span>Banana</span></div>
    <div><span>Mango</span></div>
    <div><span>Strawberry</span></div>
    <div><span>Jackfruit</span></div>
    
    <div><span>red</span></div>
    <div><span>blue</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```